# jQuery Ajax JSONP Post call to WCF Service mostly gets 400 Bad Request

Tags: json, wcf, jquery, jsonp

Hmm well there's lots here about this but I can't seem to get a JSON object through to a web service object.  The closest I can get to making this work is this example, where ID matches the string variable name in the service as follows

```
        var jsonData = { "ID": "hello" };
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://blah/blah.svc/GetPersonByID",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",  // from the server
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // to the server
            data: jsonData,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("success " + msg.Name);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.status + " " + status + " " + error);
            }
        });
```

Where the WCF service is this

```
    [OperationContract]
    [Description("Returns a person by ID.")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Person GetPersonByID(string ID);

    public Person GetPersonByID(string ID) {
        Person person = new Person {
            Name = ID,   // "Bob",
            FavoriteColor = "Red",
            UserID = 1 //int.Parse(ID)
        };
        return person;
    }
```

This returns "success ID=hello".

Why does it return ID=hello, instead of just hello?

If I use data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": "hello" })  it fails with 400 bad request

If I attempt any other data type like an int for the web service ID (instead of string) if fails.

If I attempt any more complex data types it fails.

Any thoughts???  Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the body style expected by a WCF operation is "bare", which means that the input must be sent by itself (i.e., it expects something like `"hello"`. In your case you're *wrapping* it in an object with the parameter name (`{"ID":"hello"}`).

You can either make the operation expect the wrapped input (by setting the `BodyStyle` property of the `WebInvoke` attribute to `WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` (and JSON.stringify your data), or change the parameter passed to $.ajax to simply send the JSON string (`data: "\"hello\""`).

Comment: OMG!  I've been working on this for 3 days!  You ROCK.  This resolves the problem when accessing the service from asp.net.  I have yet to test this in the jQuery but I have a good feeling about this.